# What permastrusture tags are generated out of the box right after creating custom post types and taxonomies?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, tags, rewrite-rules

I was curious: when I create a custom taxonomy or post type, what new permastructure tags are auto generated and ready to use? It seems there are no docs about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok one way to check them up is to log them somewhere after creating post types and taxonomies:

```
add_action('init','register_customs');
function register_customs(){
   // [...] create types and tax
   global $wp_rewrite;
   // log $wp_rewrite somewhere
}
```